# How to default to not use appsettings.Production in .Net

Tags: appsettings, .net-8.0

I want to default to using test server settings and only use production settings if it´s a production server. I'm having issues both that it completely ignores DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable and always uses appsettings.Production.json even if I manually tell it otherwise.

appsettings.json

```
}
  "EnvTest": "Test"
}
```

appsettings.Production.json

```
}
  "EnvTest": "Production"
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Serilog;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "test";
});


builder.Environment.EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_Environment") ?? "Default";

// If Production server overwrite default settings with production settings.
if(builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
}

Log.Information($"Starting service as {builder.Environment.EnvironmentName} with setting {builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("EnvTest")} on {RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription}");

var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

On server with set i get DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Test"

Output:

```
Starting service as Defaulted with setting Production on .NET 8.0.3
```

How can i convince the app to not use production settings?

Tried both setting DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable and manually set builder.Environment.EnvironmentName

Comment: The Host Builder validates the environment variable and [there's no no `Test` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments). Only `Development`, `Staging` and `Production`. Production is used when there's no valid option. Use `Staging` or explicitly add a Testing JSON file that overrides production settings with `.AddJson`.

Comment: Preferably I don't want to use anything and get what´s in appsettings.json

Comment: Tried setting environmentname to Staging and added an empty appsettings.Staging.json and it still uses production settings.

Comment: Add the settings you want in the correct settings file, or pass them as environment variables or CLI argumens. The settings added by a new config source override all previous ones. That's how `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.Staging.json` or `appsettings.Production.json` override `appsettings.json`. Environment variables are registered after the files and CLI parameters come last

Comment: `added an empty` an empty file has no settings so doesn't override anything. Settings are overridden based on their keys. If you don't want the settings in `appsetting.json` why put them there in the first place? Put them in `.Development.` instead

Comment: I suspect you should read how [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) works. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json` beyond the fact there's an `.AddJson("appsettings.json")` call inside the builder before other sources are added. The settings from *all* sources are converted to Key/Value pairs. Settings are overriden at the key level, which is what allows you to only specify a new log level or connection string setting in `appsettings.Production.json` instead or repeating the entire section.

Comment: I want the settings in appsettings.json but I don't get them currently. I get the settings in appsettings.Production.json, that's the problem. Oh and It's not ASP.NET

Comment: Because you use the wrong environment and wrong settings in appsettings.Staging.json. You really should check the docs, this has nothing to do with files. If a JSON has no setting keys, it can't override those settings. Settings are overridden at the key level, not the file level. If your test server had an environment variable named `Position__Title` it would override the `Position:Title` setting in *all* JSON files, because env variables have higher precedence. And if you run your application with the `/Position:Title=Cmd` parameter, it would override even the env variable

Comment: Althoug **your own code** breaks that order with `if(builder.Environment.IsProduction())` when it adds `"appsettings.Production.json"` after everything else. `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder` already registered all the settings sources in the predefined order.

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help and I seem to have failed to describe the problem properly. Maybe it´s just not possible then to stop it from using appsettings.Production.json as default.

Comment: I undestood the problem very well, and things just work the way you want already. You're making the wrong assumptions about the Configuration middleware. There's no problem with `appsettings.Production.json`. You won't fix the problem until you understand how Configuration works. I can tell you haven't read the links I posted at all, because you keep talking about *files*, when settings are only handled at the individual value level. If you want different settings for Development or Staging, add *all* the new setting values in the correct file. Keys that aren't specified aren't overriden

Comment: I think the documentation states that only one environment file is loaded and used, if that's not the case it's very unclear. 

I've tested adding the same key in appsettings.Staging.json and it still takes the value from appsettings.Production.json, so it doesn't seem to be the case.